# Spfx: Change spfx Webpart environment from sharepoint online to sharepoint on prem

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-on-prem, spfx-extensions, yeoman-generator

I have a modern web part built for sharepoint Online. I want to convert this web part to be compatible with sharepoint on-prem 2019.

I have searched and found out that I would need to use spfx version 1.4.1 for on prem-19. So I will downgrade my Spfx to 1.4.1

The confusion I have is around the content of my .yo-rc.json file

```
{
  "@microsoft/generator-sharepoint": {
    "version": "1.4.1",
    "libraryName": "Test",
    "libraryId": "",
    "environment": "spo",
    "isDomainIsolated": false,
    "isCreatingSolution": true,
    "packageManager": "npm",
    "componentType": "webpart"
  }
}
```

Here the environment is targeting 'spo'. Is it possible to make it work with out creating a new separate project? Can I Scaffold an existing projects to make it work on sharepoint on-prem 2019

Answer (score 1):

Its not just these few changes that you will help you convert.

SP ON-prem only support SPFx 1.4 which only supports React 15(not latest React with Hooks) and so other libraries dependencies change similarly and is a difference of complete dependency chain.

The closest to what you want can be achieved using workarounds like: [LINK](https://spblog.net/post/2019/08/08/build-sharepoint-framework-solutions-for-on-premises-sharepoint-with-any-version-of-react-typescript-or-office-ui-fabric-react)